# Have Plotly chart show only selected menu option on load

Tags: python, plotly

I am using a data set that has one numerical column (value) and two categorical columns (bin and cat):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Cat': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
        'Bin': ['low', 'low', 'med', 'med', 'high', 'high'],
        'value': [17, 22, 12, 23, 29, 11] 
    }
)
```

I am using Plotly Express to render a stacked bar chart. Everything is working except when the page first loads the chart shows all of the data instead of only the selected option from the menu.

How do I make the chart match the selection in the dropdown by showing only the low bin data when the chart first loads?

```py
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.bar(
  df,
  x='value',
  y='Cat',
  color='Bin'
)
fig.update_layout(
    showlegend=False,
    updatemenus=[
        {
            'buttons': [
                {
                    'label': t.name,
                    'method': 'restyle',
                    'args': [{'visible': [t2.name == t.name for t2 in fig.data]}],
                }
                for t in fig.data
            ],
            'x': 0.3,
            'xanchor': 'left',
            'y': 1.2,
        'yanchor': 'top',
        }
    ]
)



fig.show()
```

this is what the chart looks like on load
[image: char on load with menu selected but all data showing]

The menu show the low bin but data from all the bins is visible.

[here is a working version](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1vLESoYPSs0-i6s04NlvOjjs3gJOkZC3z?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be other ways to do this besides my suggestion, but in the case of this graph, it consists of three bars, so setting only low to display and the rest to hide will work as desired. Usually, it is common to add all of them to the button.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Cat': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
        'Bin': ['low', 'low', 'med', 'med', 'high', 'high'],
        'value': [17, 22, 12, 23, 29, 11] 
    }
)

fig = px.bar(
  df,
  x='value',
  y='Cat',
  color='Bin'
)

fig.data[1].visible= False # update
fig.data[2].visible= False # update

fig.update_layout(
    showlegend=False,
    updatemenus=[
        {
            'buttons': [
                {
                    'label': t.name,
                    'method': 'restyle',
                    'args': [{'visible': [t2.name == t.name for t2 in fig.data]}],
                }
                for t in fig.data
            ],
            'x': 0.3,
            'xanchor': 'left',
            'y': 1.2,
        'yanchor': 'top',
        }
    ]
)


fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the simple solution. Accepted as the answer. The actual data has many bins, all at different scales, making a complete stacked view difficult to interpret.